# QwtPlot3D build on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qmake, qwt

I downloaded QwtPlot3D project from here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/qwtplot3d/files/

When I run qmake on the project file in the zip, I get following result:

```
WARNING: Unable to generate output for: C:/path/Makefile.Debug [TEMPLATE vclib]
QIODevice::write: device not open
```

Same when I try to build from QtCreator.

Any ideas ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the file in a location that does not exist on the computer.
You could change the location of the folder to be created.

Comment: I will check and get back here. Thanks.